# Android: Get values from array without key from JSON file on server

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I wanted to get value from array inside an array from this JSON file link [JSON file link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/y2oo8). I wanted to get values from "data" array which is inside "meta" and "view". Since, data array does not have key I am unable to display the data in my application.

Here is my code:
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="432dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:text="PowerBall result" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.abina.getwebdata;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassification;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;

import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resultParse();
            }
        });

    }

    public void  resultParse(){
        String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/y2oo8";

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("meta");

                            for (int i= 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject dview = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONArray jsonViewArray = dview.getJSONArray("view");

                                for (int l =0 ; l<jsonViewArray.length();l++){
                                    JSONObject columns = jsonViewArray.getJSONObject(l);
                                    JSONArray jsonColumnsArray = columns.getJSONArray("data");

                                    for (int k =0;k<jsonColumnsArray.length();k++){
                                        JSONObject data = jsonColumnsArray.getJSONObject(k);

                                        String name = data.toString();

                                        textView.append(name+"\n\n");
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `"data"` array is not inside **"meta" and "view"**. It's on top at the same level where is `"meta"`.

Comment: Thank you. Since, it was a big file I could not find out. How did you easily find out "data" array is not inside "meta" and "view"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, `"data"` array is not inside `"meta" and "view"`. It's on top at the same level where is `"meta"`.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
```

**Answer of second question :** If you want to display first element of the `data` json array then do the following

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
if (jsonArray!=null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
    String data = jsonArray.optString(0, null);
    textView.setText(data);
}
```

Result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Since, the values inside "data" has no key. How could we display the values from first array inside data array in a textview.

Comment: Did not understand what does it mean **How could we display the values from first array inside data array in a textview.**. Also this is the another requirement, you shouldn't had to withdrawn your answer as it has solve the original one.

Comment: I am unable display the values inside "data" in a textview.

Comment: You had to do in the same how you doing in your question , by iterating the array elements.This is what you have in your code `JSONArray jsonColumnsArray = columns.getJSONArray("data");

                                    for (int k =0;k<jsonColumnsArray.length();k++){
                                        JSONObject data = jsonColumnsArray.getJSONObject(k);

                                        String name = data.toString();

                                        textView.append(name+"\n\n");
                                    }` Does it not work ?

Comment: `JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
        if(jsonArray.length()>0){
            textView.append(jsonArray.optString(0,null));
        }` This should serve your job.

Comment: Thank you. I could get (1,"473F0579-3060-42E8-95C6-671B43230276",1,1362743858,"706580",1362743858,"706580","{\n}","2010-02-03T00:00:00","17 22 36 37 52 24","2"). If you don't mind how could I display ("2010-02-03T00:00:00","17 22 36 37 52 24","2") this value. This is for the first index. How do I do the same for the last index.[1100,"ED18E865-198F-4FD6-A9BA-640226DB10D0",1100,1534672866,"708543",1534672866,"708543",null,"2018-08-18T00:00:00","24 34 52 61 67 16","3"]. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
            // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of json.
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayData.length();i++){
                JSONArray jsonItem = jsonArrayData.getJSONArray(i);
                //take each one of them from the jsonarray and use it
                String zero = jsonItem.get(0).toString();
                String one = jsonItem.get(1).toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what is the benefit of having `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);` considering that `response` is already a `JSONObject`?

Comment: you said you want data from inside meta and view.. first of all "meta" and "view" are json objects not json array... second "data" array below are not inside the "meta".

Comment: Thank you. Since, the values inside "data" has no key. How could we display the values from first array inside data array in a textview.

Comment: It does not display like (1,"473F0579-3060-42E8-95C6-671B43230276",1,1362743858,"706580",1362743858,"706580","{\n}","2010-02-03T00:00:00","17 22 36 37 52 24","2") which is first element inside "data".

Comment: check my edited answer..i tried it myself its is working 100%...
hope it helps!!!

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help. It means a lot.

Comment: glad it helped mate...please accept the answer for others to benefit also thanks!!

Comment: glad it helped mate...please accept the answer for others to benefit also thanks!!